# shared folder in play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In a play 2.0 application, I need an additional source folder (a shared folder that I can reuse in other projects) beside the "app" folder.

So I created the folder in the root directory and added those lines to the the Build.scala file:

```
sourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory / "shared"
javaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory / "shared"
```

Without any effect, I'm still getting a compilation error: "package foo.bar does not exist".

The next thing I tried is creating a module for the shared folder:

```
val sharedFolder = Project("shared", file("modules/shared"))
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    ebeanEnabled := false).dependsOn(sharedFolder)
```

That works, except in this case the appDependencies are not available in the module, so I still get compile errors. Any ideas how I can fix the dependencies for the module or add an additional source folder to my main project?

Comment: Why not to create a separate play project for the shared module and link it as a dependency in the main app? Obviously, app dependencies then should be specified explicitly for the module.

Comment: Why is the file pointing to file("modules/shared")? Assuming your structure like /project/app, /project/conf etc... Is it like /project/shared or /project/modules/shared?

Comment: @Vlad ok that would work, thanks. Bit overhead though.

Comment: @Georg: if "project" is my root folder, I have the module in /project/modules/shared/src/main/java

Comment: @AndreasKa The only overhead is additional dependencies defined twice. On the other hand, Play will generate a nice project for your IDE (even changes in the module project will be picked up immediately by Play in runtime) so that you won't see any difference when working with such project organisation, and at the same time you will have your module as a pure reusable component.

Comment: @Vlad: I tried that out now. I can compile the subproject without any issues, but when I compile my main project, I am getting compile errors since the dependencies are not available for the subproject. I am just using the org.json library in the subproject. do you have a working buildfile for both the main-project and the sub-project?